# Start Apollo Server test client on different port

Tags: testing, graphql, integration-testing, apollo-server, apollo-server-testing

How do I start the Apollo Server test client on a different port?

Example from the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/testing/testing/):

```
const { createTestClient } = require('apollo-server-testing');

...

  // use the test server to create a query function
  const { query } = createTestClient(server);

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server's port is irrelevant when using the test client. The client doesn't make an HTTP call and just calls the [executeOperation](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/39024ce3d8e19d1ac8a4ba78295d79f801401acb/packages/apollo-server-core/src/ApolloServer.ts#L856) directly as shown [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/master/packages/apollo-server-testing/src/createTestClient.ts) in the source code.

Comment: Oh right. This makes sense. I wonder why I was getting an EADDRINUSE earlier...